# RegEx - Multiple expressions

Tags: angular, regex

I need to my input field to obey these 2 expressions:

1 - `/^[^.\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']*[^\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']*[^.\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']+$/`

2 - `/^[^\s].*/`

1. Means that the input cannot have these special characters and
   can't end with `.`
2. Means that the input cannot start with a blank space

Is there a way that can use these two expressions like:

```
Validators.pattern(/^[^.\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']*[^\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']*[^.\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']+$/ && /^[^\s].*/)])]
```

Comment: You need to use negative look-ahead, like this: `^(?!.*\*)(?!.*\.$)` and add your stuff to it. `^(?!.*\*)` means doesn't contain a `*` and `(?!.*\.$)` means doesn't end with `.` You can add your other rules the same way. It's a better way to validate lines even if the expressions can be combined somehow.

Comment: You can actually easily merge these two into a single regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose multiple validators:

```
Validators.compose(
    Validators.pattern('<pattern A>'),
    Validators.pattern('<pattern B>'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/^[^.\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']*[^\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']*[^.\?\\\/\:\*\<\>\|\"\']+$/` can be written as `/^[^.?\\\/:*<>|"']*[^?\\\/:*<>|"']*[^.?\\\/:*<>|"']+$/` if all unnecesary backslashes are removed.

Then, the `/^[^\s].*/` regex just requires a string to start with a non-whitespace char.

So, all you need is to add a `(?=\S)` lookahead at the start:

```js
Validators.pattern(/^(?=\S)[^.?\\\/:*<>|"']*[^?\\\/:*<>|"']*[^.?\\\/:*<>|"']+$/)
//                   ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PENDou/1).

It also seems too redundant to have two optional subpatterns at the start, see `[^.?\\\/:*<>|"']*[^?\\\/:*<>|"']*`. It makes sense to further shrink it to

```js
Validators.pattern(/^(?=\S)[^?\\\/:*<>|"']*[^.?\\\/:*<>|"']+$/)
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\S)` - a lookahead requiring the first char to be a char other than whitespace
- `[^?\\\/:*<>|"']*` - zero or more chars other than `?`, `\`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `"` and `'`
- `[^.?\\\/:*<>|"']+` - one or more chars other than `.`, `?`, `\`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `"` and `'`
- `$` - end of string.